# How to separate the groupedby data in diferent columns of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

How do i turn this

| object | Name | Color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fruit | Banana | Yellow |
| Fruit | Apple | Red |
| Fruit | Melon | Green |
| Car | Fiat | White |
| Car | BMW | Black |
| Car | NaN | NaN |

In to this?

| object | Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | Color1 | Color2 | Color3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fruit | Banana | Apple | Melon | Yellow | Red | Green |
| Car | Fiat | BMW | NaN | White | Black | NaN |

I've searched the pandas documentation, but couldn't find a solution to this

Read the pandas documentation, tried some diferent methods of groupby

Comment: After posting an answer I found that this has already been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62923778/applying-pandas-pivot-using-existing-column-names-with-suffix. Ended up with a similar answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With inspiration from comment by @mitoRibo, here is an answer:

```
df["N"] = df.assign(N=1).groupby("object")["N"].cumsum().map("Name{}".format)
df["C"] = df.assign(C=1).groupby("object")["C"].cumsum().map("Color{}".format)
out = df.pivot(index=["object"], columns=["N", "C"], values=["Name", "Color"])
out.columns = [t[1] if t[0] == "Name" else t[2] for t in out.columns]
print(out)

         Name1  Name2  Name3  Color1 Color2 Color3
object                                            
Car       Fiat    BMW    NaN   White  Black    NaN
Fruit   Banana  Apple  Melon  Yellow    Red  Green
```

Answer (score 2):

Feels inefficient, but you can first create a new column to keep track of the number of times each item is listed before `melt`ing, creating the new column names, then `pivot`ing back.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#original df
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'object': ['Fruit', 'Fruit', 'Fruit', 'Car', 'Car', 'Car'],
    'Name': ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Melon', 'Fiat', 'BMW', np.nan],
    'Color': ['Yellow', 'Red', 'Green', 'White', 'Black', np.nan],
})

#add an 'object_count' column to df
df['object_count'] = df.groupby('object').cumcount().add(1)

#melt df to long form
long_df = df.melt(id_vars=['object','object_count'])

#append 'object_count' to the variable column
long_df['variable'] += long_df['object_count'].astype(str)

#pivot the table back to wide form
final_df = long_df.pivot(
    index='object',
    columns='variable',
    values='value',
).reset_index()

final_df.columns.name = None #get rid of the 'variable' text at the top right of the table

#note, the output table isn't sorted by row or col the same as your expected output
#(it's sorted alphabetically for both)
#but you can do this or find help if it's important

print(final_df)
```

Output

```
  object  Color1 Color2 Color3   Name1  Name2  Name3
0    Car   White  Black    NaN    Fiat    BMW    NaN
1  Fruit  Yellow    Red  Green  Banana  Apple  Melon
```